# Regularly receiving suspicious certificate errors online

Tags: certificates

For the past few weeks, I have frequently been receiving error messages from websites stating that the certificate is invalid. This tends to happen for a while and then resolve itself. Other devices on the same network connection are also experiencing odd behaviour, including a very sporadic internet connection that is either very slow or turns on and off. We had an engineer visit this week to diagnose whether there was a faulty connection, but they left, happy that the connection is working properly.

I understand that receiving 'bad' certificates can sometimes be a sign of the system clock or internet settings being poorly configured. I had assumed this might be the case, until I interrogated one of these 'invalid certificate' messages more closely (from Firefox on Mac):

> Web sites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for eur03.safelinks.protection.outlook.com. The certificate is only valid for the following names: cloudflare-dns.com, *.cloudflare-dns.com, one.one.one.one, 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1, <...>

The website I was trying to visit in this case has nothing to do with cloudflare, and the links above lead to a website that appears to be selling a VPN-type service.

Should I be concerned that my internet connection has been tapped, and what would be the appropriate action to take to shake this off?

Comment: Quite possibly, someone on your LAN is trying to MITM. Especially since you said multiple clients are experiencing this?

Comment: It does seem like a MITM attack, but I doubt it would originate within our LAN. We are in a remote location and noone on the network would have the skill or inclination. Is it possible that a MITM attack like this could be launched remotely? And can anything be done about it?

Comment: Perhaps you are using a VPN which brings all clients onto the same subnet? When you access a webpage, the session might be getting routed through this rogue node using ARP spoofing. Perhaps ask your network admin to see if multiple nodes have the same IP addresses (possibly the network gateway address?).

Comment: I'm not using a VPN, but it certainly looks as though my traffic is trying to be routed through a VPN somewhere.

Comment: Is this only happening when you open links from email?

Comment: @EsaJokinen not exclusively. Certainly that happens occasionally, but sometimes it can be when I am just visiting a fairly typical website (e.g. amazon.com); sometimes I get a notification from the native Calendar app in OSX; sometimes Outlook shouts about it. The certificate always includes those "CloudFlare" addresses – which is a service that we don't use. It does seem to be related to periods of poor internet connectivity though which does make me wonder if it's just something to do with the certificate received being incomplete. Doesn't explain CloudFlare, but that could be a red herring

Comment: Ok. I was suspecting a bug in Microsoft Safelinks, but doesn't look like one. Could this be a DNS related issue, DNS incorrectly replying with `1.1.1.1` from time to time. This would mean that the browser is trying to access arbitrary pages on Cloudflare's `1.1.1.1`, which then replies with its own valid certificate - just not valid for the hostname you are looking for.

Comment: Possibly..? I know our internet connection is pretty shoddy – we have had a lot of physical problems with the wires being hit by floods etc. AFAIK there are no current problems but I could be wrong. Is it possible that the request is being sent to 1.1.1.1 in error as a result of dropped packets? Sorry this is a rookie suggestion; I'm no expert in these things which is why I've come here.

Comment: Could it be related to improperly configured certs after the root certs that expired in early June?

Comment: Good idea @mbomb007, but my system was new in 2017, up-to-date and this happened on Amazon, amongst other fairly high-profile sites.

Comment: If you are getting valid CloudFlare certs, it looks more like a misconfiguration somewhere. What DNS server are you using?